# css / jQuery attribute selector in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

In the question I'm essentially looking for some help with a regular expression.

Here is the pattern I'm currently using:

```
 preg_match_all("~\[([^\]]+)=([^\[]+)\]~", $search, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

That works fine for :

```
'[name=test][type=select]'
```

Result:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [1-5]   `name`
2.  [6-10]  `test`
MATCH 2
1.  [12-16] `type`
2.  [17-23] `select`
```

**[demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/jA6xR0/1)**

The problem comes with

```
'[for=event[schedule]]'
```

Obviously whats happening is the extra `[`'s and `]`'s prevent the regex from matching the string.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to fix the regex pattern to get this output:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [1-3]   `for`
2.  [5-19]  `event[schedule]`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to optionally match the `[...]` part:

```
preg_match_all('~\[([^\]]+)=([^\]\[]+(?:\[[^\]]+\])?)\]~', $search, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

To require it:

```
preg_match_all('~\[([^\]]+)=([^\]\[]+\[[^\]]+\])\]~', $search, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```